# The most recent rows in for each type/agent

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, distinct

I have a table (still on MySQL 5.7) with lots of data. This table is written by some scripts. It works like a "checkin", where each agent is checking in in some period of time. It looks like below.

| id | agent | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | ok | 2023-03-16 12:27:03 |
| 2 | jeff | degraded | 2023-08-31 00:01:13 |
| 100 | tom | ok | 2023-10-03 12:00:00 |
| 101 | jeff | ok | 2023-10-03 11:59:00 |

I'd like to pick the most fresh line per each agent. So in above example I'd like to get row 100 and 101.

I use following script, but it turns out only first two rows. I tried changing order by id or timestamp ASC/DESC.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM db_table ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as agnt GROUP BY agent
```

How to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a multitude of ways to solve this kind of problem. I typically use a [window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) to enumerate the rows by a specific sort criteria. Then you can select only the rows you want using that enumeration.

Unfortunately in MySQL 5.7 and older, window functions don't exist, so an alternative solution is using a correlated subquery like so:

```
SELECT
    id,
    agent,
    status,
    timestamp
FROM checkin AS C1
WHERE timestamp =
(
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS LatestTimestamp
    FROM checkin AS C2
    WHERE C1.agent = C2.agent -- Join on the same agent
)
```

Note that this only works if the `timestamp` isn't duplicated for the same `agent` in the table.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'm not sure if this is version of MySQL Workbench which doesn't support this kind window function (it has problem with "WITH").

Comment: @Marek Ah, I missed your MySQL version. It's because 5.7 doesn't support CTEs. I just updated my answer to use a subquery for the window function instead, which should work for you.

Comment: Now I tried and still some incompatibility in this line "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agent ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC) AS SortId". MySQL Workbench suggest "(" before partition is not expected there.

Comment: @Marek ah interesting, I guess window functions also aren't supported in that old version of MySQL. I've updated my answer once more with an alternative solution.

Comment: Now it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marek Sure thing, np!